# Apache Http Client - Redirect URL gets URL decoded. Any way to work around?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use the apache http client library (4.5.14). I'm doing a request which receives a 302 along with a `Location` response header.

The `Location` response header is URL encoded, but somehow the apache http client library seems to URL decode it and attempts to make a request to the now URL decoded url.

This is the `Location` header in the response :

> 2023-10-31 07:25:38.899 DEBUG --- [           main] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-2 << Location: https://[hostname-redacted]/temp/AB-C0244_BONNIE_BANKS_O_LOCH_LOMOND16987335293607/AB-C0244_TK22.2_BONNIE_BANKS_O%27_LOCH_LOMOND_General_Underscore_Abaco_Music_Library_(PRS).wav?Expires=1698733651&Signature=ZkxxNJhbLrX84ykFuFA7pKEhc05pCrUGJ8oQNjUbCswvh5o8K2k7W3HlG16zrX4EO2co4M1074X2uoHAlpTjnqhSz6FSnWeFud0LIEU6z99nvYmll6bgj1VQg~FqFz2aGLHF9qzRIeM2e73gWBU8bu5EVg5X5n-m8gdyz6-zg5M_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIBH6A7AA3GUADXUQ

This is the URL which the apache http client then attempts to request :

> 2023-10-31 07:25:38.902 DEBUG --- [           main] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Executing request GET /temp/AB-C0244_BONNIE_BANKS_O_LOCH_LOMOND16987335293607/AB-C0244_TK22.2_BONNIE_BANKS_O'*LOCH_LOMOND_General_Underscore_Abaco_Music_Library*(PRS).wav?Expires=1698733651&Signature=ZkxxNJhbLrX84ykFuFA7pKEhc05pCrUGJ8oQNjUbCswvh5o8K2k7W3HlG16zrX4EO2co4M1074X2uoHAlpTjnqhSz6FSnWeFud0LIEU6z99nvYmll6bgj1VQg~FqFz2aGLHF9qzRIeM2e73gWBU8bu5EVg5X5n-m8gdyz6-zg5M_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIBH6A7AA3GUADXUQ HTTP/1.1

I've tried using a custom redirect strategy, but it doesn't help. Somehow the URL seems to be URL decoded after any `RedirectStrategy` has handed off the URI.

Is there a way for me to hook into a request, to ensure that the request url is URL encoded?

**Update**

Having investigated this one even further, it seems that [DefaultRedirectStrategy](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRedirectStrategy.java) and `getLocationURI` is to blame.

At some point, it does :

```
if (config.isNormalizeUri()) {
  uri = URIUtils.normalizeSyntax(uri);
}
```

From [what I can read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization), this should (among other things) decode percent-encoded triplets of unreserved characters. However, in my case it also decodes `%27` - which seems to be wrong.

**UPDATE 2 : code which demonstrates the issue**

Note! To see what's going on here, you need to enable debug logs for `org.apache.http`. You also need the following dependency in a `pom.xml`.

In the debug logs, you will see that the redirect to `/test%27in` will be attempted as `/test'in`.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.14</version>
  </dependency>
```

```
package test;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

public class ApacheTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/test", new RedirectHttpHandler());
        server.createContext("/test'in", new SuccessHttpHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();

        String uri = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test";
        ApacheTest t = new ApacheTest();
        t.doRequest(uri);

        server.stop(0);
    }
    
    private CloseableHttpClient getClient() {
        RequestConfig requestConfig =
                RequestConfig.custom().setNormalizeUri(true).build();

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient =
                HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
        
        return httpClient;
    }
    
    private void doRequest(String uri) {
        try {
            CloseableHttpClient c = getClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
            CloseableHttpResponse response = c.execute(get);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                throw new Exception("Expected 200 OK");
            }

            System.out.println("Got 200 OK!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static class RedirectHttpHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            t.getResponseHeaders().add("Location", "/test%27in");
            t.sendResponseHeaders(302, 0);
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.close();
        }
    }    
    
    public static class SuccessHttpHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String response = "This is the response";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Can you include the actual code you're using? It seems like you could reduce this down to a complete compilable example. This seems like a problem that shouldn't exist. If your server is providing a valid redirect URL and the http client is following redirects. I would expect it to work.

Comment: @matt I just set up a simple webserver with two endpoints locally : /test and /test'in. The /test endpoint gave a 302 redirect to /test%27in. It appears that, even though apache http client doesn't preserve the %27, it works locally. Could be that it differers between web server implementations though.

Comment: Aren't you setting normalize uri to false in your updated example? I thought the issue was occuring after a check to normalize uri.

Comment: Is the url-decoding actually causing a problem? I think it's doing it because the `'` character doesn't have any special significance in the http(s) scheme.

Comment: @k314159 the URL decoding of the ' character is the very essence. The ' characters is a reserved character, and I would expect that character to remain URL encoded.

Comment: See the [relevant section in the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2): "If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be percent-encoded before the URI is formed." Also note that there are two types of reserved character, gen and sub. The `'` character is in the sub category. It has no special purpose in HTTP(S) and it would not conflict, therefore by the quoted sentence it does not have to be encoded.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround that is specific to the problem on hand, but it may be possible to make a general solution out of it.

> **Note:** I simulated the condition using a SpringBoot endpoint that redirects to another endpoint on the same server.
>
> (I feel that is a correct simulation. But will help if you verify that. `http://localhost:8080/sample/redirect` redirects to `http://localhost:8080/sample/redReceive/ABC%27DEF`)

Create a subclass of `DefaultRedirectStrategy` class and override the `createLocation( String )` method. This method receives the redirect URL, which you can massage and create a `URI` out of. Here, we can encode `%` character, so that the "encoded triplet" (using your wording) is changed and `27` is retained. So, when the actual decoding happens, we get back `%27`.

Like this:

```java
public class RedirectStrat extends DefaultRedirectStrategy{
    @Override
    protected URI createLocationURI( String location ) throws ProtocolException {
        try {
            System.out.println( "Redirect requested for: " + location );

            // Encode '%' to its HEX, so that the URLUtils.normalizeUri() will only convert '%'
            String url = location.replaceAll( "%27", "%2527" );

            System.out.println( "Redirect changed to: " + url );

            return new URI( url );
        }
        catch( URISyntaxException e ){
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }
}
```

Now, use this in the `HttpClientBuilder` thus:

```java
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy( new RedirectStrat() ).build();
```